# Jenkins : Error accessing parameters in groovy for a Parameterized Build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to access choice parameters set in the **This build is parameterized** in a **Groovy build script**, for a Jenkins freestyle job.

[image]

I tried using the List as `println {params.List}` but it did not work and gave following output :

[image]

I have referred other similar posts on Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to have worked for me.
I have also tried `params.List` `{List}` `List` and got following error with`${env.List}` & `${params.List}`

*groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@159f1360]
11:12:48 Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure)*

How should I be calling the List correctly such that it prints out the choice I selected while running build with parameters?
Looking for some guidance on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `$List` from properties and using the new variable 'props_list' in script worked!

[image]